# Convexity of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

I have a problem in which I need to find the minimum of the function $f:\mathbf{C}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ given by

$$f(s) = v^*M(s)^*M(s)v$$

with $v \in \mathbf{C}^{n+1}$ and so that $|v_i|$ decreases logarithmically , and $M(s) \in \mathbf{C}^{(n+1)\times (n+1)}$ is a sort of lower triangular Pascal matrix:

$$M(s) = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ s & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \binom{n}{0}s^n & \cdots &\binom{n}{k}s^{n-k} & \cdots & \binom{n}{n}\end{array}\right]$$
with $|s| < 1$. I have plotted $f$ for some different values of $v$ and it seems to be "convex" (I'm not really familiar with the concept of convexity for complex functions, but the minimum seems to be global anyway), so that I can easily find the global minimum. However, I would like to prove formally that the minimum is global. I tried to write $f$ as a sum and got

$$f(s) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\left(\sum_{k=0}^i\binom{i}{k}v_k^*s(^{i-k})^*\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^i\binom{i}{k}v_ks^{i-k}\right)\right)$$

Calling $f_i(s)$ each term of the sum over $i$, we can write

$$ f_i(s) = \sum_{k=0}^i\sum_{l=0}^i\binom{i}{k}\binom{i}{l}v_k^*v_l(s^{i-k})^*s^{i-l}$$

and then

$$f_i(s) = w^*\left[\begin{array}{ccccc} 
\binom{i}{i}^2|v_i|^2 & \cdots & \binom{i}{i}\binom{i}{k}v_i^*v_k & \cdots & \binom{i}{i}\binom{i}{0}v_i^*v_0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\binom{i}{i}\binom{i}{0}v_0^*v_i & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \binom{i}{0}^2|v_0|^2
\end{array}\right]w := w^*\Phi_iw$$

with $w = [1 \; \cdots \; s^i]^T$.

After this, I'm blocked... I don't think we can simply use positive definiteness of $\Phi_i$ to conclude, due to the special structure of $w$... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you expect this to be convex in $s$ ?

Comment: @dohmatob I'm not sure it is convex, but as I said, I plotted it for several values of v and it seems to be, so it would be nice if I could show it explicitly, and hence guarantee that the minimum I find is the global minimum.

Comment: Finding the hessian is too complicated? The last one looks like a manageable expression